# Algebra Problem: $a + 1/b = b + 1/c = c + 1/a = t $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

a, b, c are distinct reals such that $$a + 1/b = b + 1/c = c + 1/a = t $$for some real t. Show that t 
= -abc
I tried using continued fractions to isolate a,b and c but equations of degree more than 2 are formed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just quite laborious.
We firstly randomly select a variable as free variable, say this time we choose $a$. Treat the condition as three separate ones.
We have:
$$a+1/b=t \text{ in which we solve for b}$$
$$c+1/a=t \text{ in which we solve for c}$$
$$b+1/c=t \text{ in which we solve for c with b obtained from (1)}$$
And the $c$ obtained from the two equation should be the same. We got a new equation with only $a$ and $t$:
$$\frac {a-t}{ta-{t}^{2}+1}=\frac {ta-1}{a}$$
which is equivalent to:
$$({t}^{2}-1){a}^{2}+(t-{t}^{3})a+{t}^{2}-1=0$$
Solving this yields t can equal to any of $1,-1,\frac {{a}^{2}+1}{a}$.

However, they are said to be three distinct reals (or $a=c$), so $t=1,-1$. (*-1 seems to be incorrect in the next step, not sure about my calculation*)

Now you substitute the possible values of $t$ to the original equation. Solve the three equations and verify the result.

It seems $t$ is just a trap that since it is fixed by the three conditions as implied in the comment.

Comment: Why can't $t=\frac{a^2+1}{a}$

Comment: If $t=\frac{a^2+1}{a}$, then $t=a+1/a=c+1/a$, contradicts with your condition that they are distinct reals.

Comment: Did you actually solve the cubic in t.If yes then how?

Comment: @user348631 I didn't *actually* solved the equation, I did a long division over t-1.

Comment: What did you divide by$ t-1$

Comment: Just see my updated answer, which include a equation in which you can clearly see you can factor out $t^2-1$  actually.