# If $ a+ \frac{1}{b}= b+ \frac{1}{c}= c + \frac{1}{a} = k$ , how to find the value of $k$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a,b,c$ be distinct (non-zero) such that

$ a+ \frac{1}{b}= b+ \frac{1}{c}= c + \frac{1}{a} = k$

how do I find the value of k ?

Comment: Please rewrite the equations with MathJax. I, at least, don't understand what you mean by the numbers. What is "1b" and "1c", etc ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Possibly related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917588/algebra-problem-a-1-b-b-1-c-c-1-a-t

Comment: thanks everyone, I'll try .I need time to get used to this

Comment: If you negate all of $a,b,c$, you get the opposite value of $k$ too. And $k=0$ is clearly impossible since $a,b,c$ would then need to have pairwise opposite signs...

Comment: from value of $abc$ , how to find $k$?

Comment: @user, my answer to that question *starts* by finding your $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: From the second equation we get $$b=k-\frac{1}{c}$$ so we get
$$a(kc-1)+c=k(kc-1)$$ and wwith $$c=k-\frac{1}{a}$$ and we get
$$a(k(k-\frac{1}{a})-1)+k-\frac{1}{a}=k(k(k-\frac{1}{a})-1)$$
simplifying and factorizing we get
$$(k-1)(k+1)(a^2-ka+1)=0$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: Thanks so  much , helpful.

Comment: Is your problem solved now?

Comment: Yes.  solved . after problem solved, is there something I have to do? this is my first time MSE.

Comment: No,no, but you can give me some points, if you want.

Comment: I tried. but MSE says "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded " .... I just came here and this is the first question. so I have only one reputaion. so I can't vote..

Comment: Ok, then have a nice day, with systems of equations.